# Is asking questions not directly tied to game development allowed?

Tags: discussion

A few times in the Gamedev SE, I see questions that even though they seem to be related to game development (obvious variable names, Class names, etc..), but aren't directly relevant to any issue that concerns game development.

As in you would be better off asking it in StackOverflow, where you'll probably receive an explanation coming from a community that includes a ton of developers who will know the best and most efficient ways to reply to your question. Sometimes there are general physics/mathematics related questions that can also be answered more efficiently in the suiting forums.

So shouldn't it be better to redirect the people who ask their questions here to where they would receive better answers? It'll be much more helpful to them.

Comment: If you see something new (necroing old posts isn't terribly helpful) that you feel is better suited for another SE site flag it for moderator attention or bring it up in chat and see how others feel on it, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Will do from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like you describe is better-suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is for specific problems with actual code. Programmers is where questions that deal with programming as a discipline go.

Answer (score 1):

Questions that are not about game development aren't considered on-topic here. This is pretty well-established in the site rules; there's a dedicated close reason specifically for general programming questions that are a better fit for StackOverflow.

Being "about game development" means "would a game developer reasonably be expected to give a much better answer than any other sort of developer?" If the answer there is "no," it's generally not a question suitable for this site and should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: I totally agree with your answer, but the forum is full of them...